# Why QR Code from endroid not display correctly in codeigniter 4

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, qr-code, codeigniter-4

Currently i'm using class from https://github.com/endroid/qr-code

i put below code as sample from github :

```
$qrCode = new QrCode('Life is too short to be generating QR codes');

header('Content-Type: '.$qrCode->getContentType());
echo $qrCode->writeString();
```

But the result become like this
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put $qrCode->setWriterByExtension('svg'); and it's working